# Get Read and write permission for CSV file in android 13

Tags: android, android-13

I am trying to read and write a file in android 13.

AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static String[] permissions() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
            return new String[]{
                    android.Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES,
                    android.Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO
            };
        } else {
            return new String[]{
                    android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                    android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            };
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions(), 23);

        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), "abc.csv");
        android.util.Log.d("OK", "onCreate: " + file.canRead());
    }
}
```

I am getting canRead permission always false. What am I missing?

Comment: You do not have read access to arbitrary content in `Documents/` on Android 11+. Please use the Storage Access Framework (`ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` / `ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument`) and let the user choose where on the user's device (or in the user's cloud storage) the user's CSV content resides.

Answer (score 1):

On an Android 13 device your app does not need any permission to create files in public directories on external storage.

Just create them.

If you wanna read an existing file not created by your app you need to use SAF. Also no permissions needed.